# Auto-defined controller method overrides builtin Rails method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When you have a controller named `image`, Rails automatically defines helper methods such as `image_path`.

The behavior results in hiding Rails builtin-method `ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper::image_path`. This means that you won't be able to call those helpers when you have such controllers.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a solution for this. You can use [`path_to_image`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.11/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb#L277) helper as it's an alias to `image_path`.

Comment: Thanks! I looked through the source, but didn't notice that part.